# Running Linux from pendrive on Windows natively

Tags: windows, usb-drive

I am trying to find a program that allows me to run some linux distribution directly from pendrive, in windows, without the need to access the bios or to have administrator permissions.
I need something like [colinux](http://www.colinux.org/) or [ubuntu portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableubuntu/). But I need a solution that is portable and don't need administrator permissions to execute the linux distribution.
Someone knows a program like this?

Comment: With regards to admin permissions: Is it permitable to require admin permissions to install / configure some software to allow you to run the OS from the flash drive? (And the not having administrator permissions to run it.) Are any other permission changes allowed?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to have a linux environmental inside of windows try [LinuxLiveUSB creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/).  You can pick a distro and it'll install a portable VM program onto the flash drive along with the image (you can set persistence too if you like). I don't believe it requires admin privileges to run the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have too many constraints in place. If you don't have admin privileges on the Windows installation, you cannot (read *"shouldn't be able to"*) get anything running in Ring0. Unless it is possible to boot the machine from CD/USB/network(!), the only remaining option (apart from hacking Windows) is taking out the hard drive, repartitioning, preparing multi-boot and putting it back.

You could try running it in a virtual machine, but even if it works it will be rather slow without the hardware support for which the VM would require at least some access to Ring0.

That said, you can also try to play it fair and square and ask the administrator whether it would consider allowing you to run some linux on the machine somehow. Given that he/she seems to be at least a bit knowledgeable (since you mentioned you don't have access to BIOS) it might be worth a try.